# Uniformly convergent sequence of functions with jump discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to figure out if the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of functions with jump discontinuities has only jump discontinuities.

I think the answer is no, but I can't construct a counterexample for it.

Any hints?

Comment: Hint: I like your question, but there are already 2 votes to close it, because it is "missing context". You can fix this by editing. It might even help if you just include your definition of "jump discontinuity".